# eliminar titulos filtrando resultados

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un filtro de resultados pero necesito que al escribir en el recuadro de búsqueda los títulos desaparezcan; justo como lo que hace el código a continuación:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
        $('#buscar').keyup(function () {
            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('#aBuscar p').hide();
            $('#aBuscar p').filter(function () {
    return rex.test($(this).text());
   }).show();
  })
 }(jQuery));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="buscar" placeholder="Buscar">
 <div id="aBuscar">
  <h1>Titulo0</h1>
  <p>buscar</p>
  <p>encontrar</p>
  <h1>Titulo1</h1>
  <p>correr</p>
  <p>detenerse</p>
 </div>
```

La función la utilice de la respuesta de otro usuario pero solo falta que me oculte los títulos al comenzar a escribir en el recuadro de búsqueda y luego que los muestre cuando se borre todo el contenido del recuadro de búsqueda.

Agradeciendo de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes capturar eventos de teclado y cada vez que se pulse una tecla ver si el campo de búsqueda tiene algo, en ese caso, ocultas los títulos.

Comment: Hola @AntoniCobos, sencilla tu respuesta pero me funcionó.

Comment: Me alegro haberte ayudado, Suerte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo tenía que verificar si el campo de búsqueda estaba vacío o no; de no estarlo simplemente oculto los títulos.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
        $('#buscar').keyup(function () {
            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('#aBuscar p').hide();
            $('#aBuscar p').filter(function () {
    return rex.test($(this).text());
   }).show();
   if ($('#buscar').val() == "") {
    $('#aBuscar h1').show();
    return false;
   } else {
    $('#aBuscar h1').hide();
   }
  })
 }(jQuery));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="buscar" placeholder="Buscar">
        <div id="aBuscar">
            <h1>Titulo0</h1>
            <p>buscar</p>
            <p>encontrar</p>
            <h1>Titulo1</h1>
            <p>correr</p>
            <p>detenerse</p>
   </div>
```

Realmente sencillo, sólo necesitaba un poco de iluminación.